# Function in views tpl

Tags: views

How can I add a function  in my custom views .tpl page or where can I write my function and call that function in my views .tpl ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the function in any php file that gets loaded.  PHP is not sequential in loading/processing files, it will load them first then process.

Comment: You _can_, but you probably shouldn't. Keeping some sort of structure would be preferable

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of any future developer, including yourself, you should try to keep your custom functions inside your template.php file or in a module that you've created.

that is where people will expect to find functions used in templates and such.

Comment: This. A thousand times this :) Anyone who's inherited a site from a dubious developer will agree I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

Data transformation or processing should go in the preprocess function for that template. That way the template stays neat and only focused on presentation. In the preprocess function you can alter, remove, or add new variables as you please. These variables will then be available in the associated template. As user5482 mentions, it should go in either your theme's template.php, or in a custom module. If you are only altering or removing a variable, then your template.php will suffice. If you are creating new variables with data not readily available it should probably go into a new module and an earlier hook in the pipeline.

Make sure to document your new variable in the template as that is the first place where themers will look for information about it.